# Tic Tac Toe in Java printing error

Tags: java, enums, tic-tac-toe

I've almost got this homework assignment finished, but I'm having some printing errors with the output. 
The game is functional, but there's a problem with methods `printOBoard` and `printXBoard` where it messes up the game board when a move is made. The problem becomes worse the longer the game goes on. Thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

private enum Tiles {
    X, O, EMPTY;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i;
    int j;
    //initialize 2d array of enum types called "board"
    Tiles[][] board = new Tiles[3][3];
    for (i=0; i<board.length; i++) 
        for (j=0; j<board.length; j++)
            board[i][j] = Tiles.EMPTY;

    //print out an empty board as a 2d array, with each tile set as "EMPTY"
    printBoard(board);
    int row, col;
    int countEmpty=0;

    //initial countEmpty count, if it's less than 1, the board is full and the game is over.
    for (i=0; i<board.length; i++)
        for (j=0; j<board.length; j++)
            if (board[i][j] == Tiles.EMPTY)
                countEmpty++;

    while (countEmpty > 0) {

        //Player O enters the row coordinate
        System.out.println("Player O's turn.");
        System.out.println("Player O:  Enter row (0, 1, or 2):");
        Scanner stdin1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        row = stdin1.nextInt();

        //Player O enters the column coordinate
        System.out.println("Player O:  Enter column (0, 1, or 2):");
        Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        col = stdin2.nextInt();
        //If the tile is empty, it was a valid move, and an 'O' is placed on the spot.  
        if (board[row][col] == Tiles.EMPTY) {
            board[row][col] = Tiles.O;
            //MOVE FOR O ********************
            printOBoard(board, row, col);
            checkWin(board);
            if (checkWin(board) == 2)
                ;
            else
                break;


        }
        //If the tile is not empty, it was not a valid move, and Player O is prompted to try again.  
        else {
            System.out.println("Space already occupied.  Please choose another.");
            System.out.println("Player O's turn.");
            //Player 0 enters the row coordinate
            System.out.println("Player O:  Enter row (0, 1, or 2):");
            stdin1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            row = stdin1.nextInt();

            //Player O enters the column coordinate
            System.out.println("Player O:  Enter column (0, 1, or 2):");
            stdin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            col = stdin2.nextInt();
            //ERROR MOVE FOR O********************
            board[row][col] = Tiles.O;
            printOBoard(board, row, col);



            checkWin(board);
            if (checkWin(board) == 2)
                ;
            else
                break;
        }



        //Player X enters the row coordinate
        System.out.println("Player X's turn.");
        System.out.println("Player X:  Enter row (0, 1, or 2):");
        Scanner stdin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        row = stdin3.nextInt();

        //Player X enters the column coordinate
        System.out.println("Player X:  Enter column (0, 1, or 2):");
        Scanner stdin4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        col = stdin4.nextInt();

        if (board[row][col] == Tiles.EMPTY) {
            board[row][col] = Tiles.X;
        printXBoard(board, row, col);
            //MOVE FOR X *************************************************
        checkWin(board);
        if (checkWin(board) == 2)
            ;
        else
            break;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Space already occupied.  Please choose another.");
            System.out.println("Player O's turn.");
            System.out.println("Player O:  Enter row (0, 1, or 2):");
            stdin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            row = stdin3.nextInt();

            //Player O enters the column coordinate
            System.out.println("Player O:  Enter column (0, 1, or 2):");
            stdin4 = new Scanner(System.in);
            col = stdin4.nextInt();
            board[row][col] = Tiles.O;
            //ERROR MOVE FOR X ****************************************
            printXBoard(board, row, col);
            checkWin(board);
            if (checkWin(board) == 2)
                ;
            else
                break;
        }

        //After both players move, we check to see if the board is full.
        countEmpty = 0;
        for (i=0; i<board.length; i++)
            for (j=0; j<board.length; j++)
                if (board[i][j] == Tiles.EMPTY)
                    countEmpty++;       

    }

}

//method printBoard prints out a grid of EMPTY's and returns nothing
private static void printBoard(Tiles board[][]) {
    int i, j;

    System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
    System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    for (i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for (j=0; j<board.length; j++){
            System.out.printf("|  " + board[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
        System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
        if (i<2)
            System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    }
    return;
}

//method printXBoard prints out the grid modified with the addition of an X after Player X's turn
private static void printXBoard(Tiles board[][], int curRow, int curCol) {
    int i, j;

    System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
    System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    for (i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for (j=0; j<board.length; j++){
            if (i == curRow && j == curCol)
                board[i][j] = Tiles.X;
            else
                ;
            System.out.printf("|  " + board[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
        System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
        if (i<2)
            System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    }
    return;
}

//method printOBoard prints out the grid modified with the addition of an X after Player X's turn
private static void printOBoard(Tiles board[][], int curRow, int curCol) {
    int i, j;

    System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
    System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    for (i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for (j=0; j<board.length; j++){
            if (i == curRow && j == curCol)
                board[i][j] = Tiles.O;
            else
                ;
            System.out.printf("|  " + board[i][j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
        System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
        System.out.println(" -----------------------------");
        if (i<2)
            System.out.println("|         |         |         |");
    }
    return;
}


//method checkWin checks all possible winning combinations for both players.
private static int checkWin(Tiles board[][]) {
    if (board[0][0] == Tiles.X && board[0][1] == Tiles.X && board[0][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[0][0] == Tiles.X && board[1][1] == Tiles.X && board[2][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[0][0] == Tiles.X && board[1][0] == Tiles.X && board[2][0] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[1][0] == Tiles.X && board[1][1] == Tiles.X && board[1][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[2][0] == Tiles.X && board[2][1] == Tiles.X && board[2][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[0][1] == Tiles.X && board[1][1] == Tiles.X && board[2][1] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[0][2] == Tiles.X && board[1][2] == Tiles.X && board[2][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (board[2][0] == Tiles.X && board[1][1] == Tiles.X && board[0][2] == Tiles.X){
        System.out.println("Player X wins!");
        return 1;
    }

    //check if player O wins
    else if (board[0][0] == Tiles.O && board[0][1] == Tiles.O && board[0][2] == Tiles.O){
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[0][0] == Tiles.O && board[1][1] == Tiles.O && board[2][2] == Tiles.O){
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[0][0] == Tiles.O && board[1][0] == Tiles.O && board[2][0] == Tiles.O){
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[1][0] == Tiles.O && board[1][1] == Tiles.O && board[1][2] == Tiles.O){
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[2][0] == Tiles.O && board[2][1] == Tiles.O && board[2][2] == Tiles.O) {
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[0][1] == Tiles.O && board[1][1] == Tiles.O && board[2][1] == Tiles.O) {
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[0][2] == Tiles.O && board[1][2] == Tiles.O && board[2][2] == Tiles.O){
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (board[2][0] == Tiles.O && board[1][1] == Tiles.O && board[0][2] == Tiles.O) {
        System.out.println("Player O wins!");
        return 0;
    }
    else 
        return 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Yikes -- that's a lot of code. Consider trying to debug it first either using a debugger or by sprinkling the code with `System.out.println("At spot 120 variable x is: " + x)` to check the values of the variables as the program is running.

Comment: The problem is with the methods for PrintOBoard and PrintXBoard- most of the code is in one method that checks for every possible winning Tic-Tac-Toe combination (called checkWin), and I put that at the very end.  The rest shouldn't be that long.  The variables seem to be correct, it's just a spacing issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in 2nd attempt to place X (if space is occupied by O), you copy pasted code from O and haven't changed player & tile.

```
System.out.println("Player O's turn.");
board[row][col] = Tiles.O;
```

It was pain to read this code -*_*-  but you'll get better eventually ;) .

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why this is happening when printing out the Letters onto your board(which I've run on my mac) is that when you're printing the letters, you're using println...since you're accompanying a certain amount of space per block you should be using printf...for example:

```
System.out.printf("%10s", LetterVariableForTurn);
```

This will give the LetterVariableForTurn 10 spaces of text to write within.

here is a link to help you more: [printf](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Hope this helps!